# How do I reset everything Python related back to default on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, python-3.5

I've been programming and learning Python for about 1.5 months now and so far I've been enjoying learning stuff and getting better through the books I'm using to learn.

But whenever I try to make my own projects, not accompanied by the book which requires extra modules to import, I always get issues.

For example, I wanted to install the YouTube api in order to fetch all YouTube titles from a channel using python3. I then realized after some time that the api only works for python 2.*.

So when I tried to install the module now for python2.* through pip, it said I already have it satisfied (which i didn't I only had it satisfied for python 3.*)

I've been getting immense problems like these repeatedly where python3 is confused for python2 and pip isn't working right etc. and a host of other problems.

So simply put, I want to reset everything python related on my Mac, including pip, homebrew, python3 and EVERYTHING else that may be extra that I downloaded for python in order to start fresh and do it right this time without problems like pip.

Comment: Also for those about to tell me to just fix the issues with pip. I can't I've read every stack post on how to do it and it never works for me.

Comment: have you tried `pip2 install` [name of package] to install modules for python2.*?

Comment: What do you mean "do it right this time without problems like pip"? Unless you really know what you are doing, and are very comfortable in Unix, I would highly advise sticking with pip.

Comment: Are you using El Capitan? If so look at this: https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/11

Comment: I have tried pip2 install, which works sometimes - Odd I know. Also I am using Sierra (unfortunately).

Comment: @user2835758 In what case does it not work?

Comment: Nevermind it does work ! I just needed to restart pyCharmIDE (closing it and reopening it). Awesome.                                                                      Now the only remaining issue I have is...  You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 9.0.1 is available. and pip2 install --upgrade pip2 doesn't work.

Comment: @user2835758 Have you tried `pip2 install --upgrade pip`?

Comment: Now the problem is backwards. pip install xxx installs to python2.7 and now I can't download any module to python3. even if I do pip3 install xxx. it says it installs it in the 2.7 directory. I love this language so fun dealing with these  stupid problems.

Comment: You may benefit from taking a break. It can be frustrating when you're new to language, and it is worth remembering that even the most experienced developers have bad days with minimal productivity. However, it is probably best if you can write in a positive or neutral fashion, since expressing great frustration may put people off helping. Readers are just volunteers after all, and they are mostly helping people here for fun.